# Are there any properties of sup?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, measure-theory, supremum-and-infimum

Can I say: 
$$\sup |f(x)-h(x)+g(x)-g(x)| = \sup|f(x)-g(x)|+ \sup|g(x)-h(x)|$$

I can't seem to find any properties of $\sup$ , so i am wondering if there is any properties that we can generalize to sup of some functions restricted on domain $x \in [0,1]$ for example

Comment: You can get an inequality ($\leq$), but not equaity in general

Comment: hmm could you elaborate on why we would get this, like some intuition such as triangle inequality....

Comment: Here's some properties via a quick google search: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum#Properties

Answer (score 4):

As said inequality holds . simple case when equality doesn't hold

$f(x) = x^2, g(x) = x^2+1 , h(x) = x^2+2$

$\sup_{[0,1]} |f(x) - g(x)| = 1 $ ,

$\sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x) - h(x)| = 2$

$\sup_{x \in [0,1]} |h(x) - g(x)| = 1$

> let $f:S \subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:S \subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ , $h:S \subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are bounded functions on $S$ which is common domain then

$$\sup_{x \in S} |f(x)  - g(x)| \leq \sup_{x \in S}|f(x) - h(x)| + \sup_{x \in S} |h(x) - g(x)|$$

proof is again based on traingle inequality:

$$\begin{align*} |f(x) - g(x)| &=  |f(x) - h(x)+ h(x) -g(x)| \\ &\leq |f(x) - h(x)| + |h(x)-g(x)|\\ &\leq \sup_{x \in S}|f(x) - h(x)| + \sup_{x \in S} |h(x) -g (x)| \\ \end{align*}  $$

so this holds for arbitrary $x$ that is

$$ \forall x , |f(x) - g(x)| \leq \sup_{x \in S}|f(x) - h(x)| + \sup_{x \in S} |h(x) -g (x)|$$

hence we have that $ \sup_{x \in S}|f(x) - g(x)| + \sup_{x \in S} |h(x) -g (x)|$ is upperbound of $|f(x) - g(x)|$ and since supremum is the least upperbound

$$\sup_{x \in S} |f(x)  - g(x)| \leq \sup_{x \in S}|f(x) - h(x)| + \sup_{x \in S} |h(x) - g(x)|$$

Comment: but how do we know sup∈|()−()| ≤|()−ℎ()|+|ℎ()−()|? could you elaborate on the step that you said last inequality comes from definition of sup, as |()−()|≤ sup |()−()|, but we can't gurantee the last equation..

Comment: @JosephRock added more detailed explanation. tell me if any thing isn't clear

Comment: but isn't it true ∀,|()−()|≤sup∈|()−g(x)| too? so sup∈|()−()| is the upper bound of |()−()| too?

Comment: @JosephRock yes that is what we used in third step.

Comment: so sup∈|()−g(x)=sup∈|()−ℎ()|+sup∈|ℎ()−()|?

Comment: no. there is an inequality not equality.

Comment: I mean both of them are upper bounds, how to show one is a larger upper bound that is more than or equal than the other?